# Как получить параметр x и y начальной точки линии и x и y конечной точки?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vector-drawable

Я хочу получить координаты x, y начальных точек и координаты x, y конечных точек всех линий на изображении, чтобы его перерисовать.
Вот мой код:

```js
const gm = require("gm");
const fs = require("fs");

function imagetolines(file) {
let result;
/*тут происходит преобразование из изображения в массив где хранятся обьекты в которых хранятся координаты начальных точек и конечных точек всех линий.
Пример массива:

[{"startx":150,"starty":54,"endx":25,"endy":56}]

*/
return result;
}
let canvas = gm(width,height,"white")//создаем холст
canvas.stroke("green",0)//устанавливаем цвет линии

result.forEach(line => {
canvas.drawLine(line[startx],line[starty],line[endx],line[endy]) //рисуем линию
});
canvas.write(file, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Вот код векторного изображения: https://pastebin.com/23qJcSHS

Comment: Было бы хорошо и соответствовало правилам сайта, чтобы в вопросе был код векторного изображения. У вас же есть исходный код? Так просто скопируйте его в вопрос и людям будет легче дать конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос. Иначе Ваш вопрос будет закрыт, как слишком общий, на который невозможно дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: Что вы имейте ввиду под "код векторного изображения"?

Comment: прочитайте свой вопрос: **У меня есть векторное изображение**  если изображение действительно векторное, то у него есть код. Если изображение в формате base64, то невозможно получить координаты, так как это по сути растровая картинка переведенная в SVG

Comment: я для близкой задачи использовал https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgpath